# Magento SSL Friendly getImageUrl();

Tags: magento

I have built a mega dropdown menu for my store which includes subcategory images.  However when I enter to the secure part of the site I get SSL errors because the images in the menu are being loaded via http rather than https

The image tag in my template file looks like this

```
<img src="<?php echo $subCategory->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

Is there a way to make it so that the images are returned with the https url when in the secure part of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the blocks_html cache in the backend and see if that makes a difference.

If it does, there are several options:

1. Leave blocks_html cache off (yuk!)
2. Add secure/nonsecure to Navigation block cache key (fun, but some work)
3. Echo the path out with a relative protocol, e.g. `src="//site.com/media/catalog/category/subcat.jpg"`

HTH
Ben

Comment: Disabling cache fixed it but obviusly I'm not going to keep it that way for production.

I like answer three best but getImageUrl() outputs full url withh http:// how else could I get the relative version?

Comment: <img src="<?php echo str_replace(array("http:","https:"),"",$subCategory->getImageUrl()); ?>" />

Answer (score 1):

str_replace(array("http://","//") That would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

But this way the image is always fetched via https - that's not a realy solution either. For example my entire page will load in half the time it takes one image to be fetched via https.